# Turtle graphics using a function

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I have this code below and I am trying to draw a colored square. The code works fine. I am curious about one thing though: why can't I define some of the attributes (see those that I commented out)under the function `drawColoredSq()`? Python doesn't run them if I do this. It only works when I define them after creating the actual turtle (turt in this case) and you can see this in the `main()` function. Why is this the case? Thank you!!!

```
import turtle
def drawColoredSq(t, sz):
    t.begin_fill()
    for side in ("side A", "side B", "side C", "side D"):
        t.forward(sz)
        t.write(side)
        t.left(90)
    t.end_fill()
#   t.shape("classic")
#   t.pensize(3)
#   t.pencolor("green")
#   t.fillcolor("blue")

def main():

    wn = turtle.Screen()
    turt = turtle.Turtle()
    wn.bgcolor("maroon")
    wn.setworldcoordinates(0,0,50,50)  
    turt.shape("classic")
    turt.pensize(3)
    turt.pencolor("green")
    turt.fillcolor("orange")
    drawColoredSq(turt, 49) 
    wn.exitonclick()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Python does run them, it's just that you're doing it after the drawing has occurred, so the results can't be seen.  Simply set the attributes before the `t.begin_fill()` call and you should be good (that's why it works when it's in `main()` too).

Comment: Setting those attributes at this point is like dipping your brush in a different color and expecting the finished paiting to change.

Comment: Wow makes so much sense now! Thank you both!

Comment: @JohnSzakmeister